# Select image by default on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON feed and I extract the values to populate a select menu with product sizes, colours/thumbnails, and get the values in an object, on submit.

**What I need is to select an image by default, if its title is matching a value of a variable declared and initialised at the top** (e.g. `var initialColour = "Wheat";`). So if initialColour is "Brown", the image with the title "Brown" should be selected by default and the sizes in the dropdown menu should reflect the selection.

This is what I am trying:

```
            if(mainImg.attr('title') == initialColour) {
                 $(this).addClass("active");
            }
```

This is on line 27 on jsfiddle link below.

[JSFIDDLE COMPLETE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/carlozdre/VpD9N/3/)

p.s. I would also appreciate any hints with regards the structure, I know its a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VpD9N/7/) does what you want?
I changed some code in two places, I left the original lines there as a reference.
Basically, I assigned the image directly to `mainImg`. Then use that when adding the class too. Also, you missed a couple of `'`s in the image html here:

```
$("<img src="+constructImageURL(mainImgID)+" id="+mainImgID+" class='colourThumb' title="+colour+" data-value='"+colour+"'> ")
```

Comment: It does select the products with matching title but the functionality is broken, it is quite a difference really (duplicate products are not removed anymore, etc)

Comment: I thought the original was broken because of the apostropes. Sorry about that, I updated the link with a corrected one.

Comment: answer accepted; is there anything you would do differently? any blatant mistakes or bad practices? I know it's not really modular or doesn't really follow any design pattern but..

Comment: It was a bit hard to read the code, proper indentation and removal of commented code would help. I wasn't really stumbled upon structural problems, but I woudn't append all the duplicate images to the dom, just to remove the duplicates couple lines later.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the issue is that you're trying to set the active thumbnail within the `for` loop, when instead, a JQuery attribute selector can be used:

```
        $("#colourId .colourThumb[title='"+initialColour+"']").each(function() {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
```

I've updated the original [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VpD9N/8/) showing that once all dynamic elements have been created, the statement above will do the trick. (Line 87)

In terms of style, it may be worth looking at one of the data binding/templating frameworks (e.g. KnockoutJS) which will make things a lot clearer in the code. There's a learning curve, but it is worth it for what you're doing.